# child div not resizing with parent

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

```
I have the following html structure for a template.php page in my website. 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    ......
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="header_div"> </div>
        <div>        

        <div id="body">
            <div id="nav_bar_left">
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="content_right">
                <?php $this->load->view($content); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="clear: both"></div>

        <div class="footer"> </div>
        <div class="copyright"><p>Copyright &copy; All Rights Reserved.</p></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I have a load_view.php view file code shown below

```
<div>   
    <?php echo form_open('main_controller/form_validate'); ?>  
    <table cellspacing="10">
        <tr>
            <td> </td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            .....
        </tr>
            ........
    </table>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

to load into content area in my controller

```
  function reg_pupil()
   {        
    $data['content'] = 'load_view';
    $this->load->view('template', $data);
   }
```

however when a resize the form doesn't resize with its parent. How do I solve that , Is there any solution for the issue?

Comment: Post the rendered html along with your CSS, so we can see what it looks like

Comment: Try this way => <table cellspacing="10" width="100%">

Answer (score 0):

Use this style for responsive.

```
<style>
@media (max-width:640px) {
table {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
}
tbody, tr {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
table td {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
}
</style>
```